# NSPredicate with swift

Tags: core-data, swift, nspredicate

Hello i'm using core data for a project heres my NSFetchedResultsController setup

```
var fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entry")
let positionDescriptor  = NSSortDescriptor(key: "position", ascending: true)
let idDescriptor  = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [positionDescriptor, idDescriptor]
fetchRequest.predicate  = NSPredicate(format: "list = %@", self.list!)
self.frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: cdc.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
self.frc?.delegate = self
```

every "Entry" entity has lists so i'm passing a list when i'm creating the view controller
the problem is that the predicate doesn't work

```
println(self.list!)
```

print nothing on the console any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this based on the information you give? You state yourself that `self.list` is empty - so show how you create the list!